# Product images are not correct in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, product-images, upgrade

I have installed Magento 2.3.2 and migrated all custom module, database, media folder from 2.2.7.
But now the product images on frontend are not correct.
I have set image size 165 * 165.
And when I try to resize via **php bin/magento catalog:image:resize**, I meet this error.

```
Area code is already set
```

How to fix this?

Comment: please check https://support.klevu.com/knowledgebase/resolving-area-code-already-set/ and https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5285

Comment: it is related to custom module you have, they using `setAreaCode` wrongly. You can debug by disabling them one by one.

Comment: I ahve fixed this issue, but after product image resize, some product images aren't correct yet. How can I config this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by upgrading Magento core module.

> MediaStorage/Console/Command/ImagesResizeCommand.

But by default, it isn't allowed for developers to change Magento core module code.

Also after image resize, though I have made a list with 45 images in my theme/ect/view.xml, but each product has only 23 resized images in cache folder.

Is there other way to fix this?

Comment: I have resized product images successfully by upgrading my view.xml file. I have had only width and height attribute, so I added aspect_ratio and frame attribute.